# Correct way to Update a Theme's Parent in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme

In Magento 2, you can specify a parent theme in a theme's `theme.xml` file.

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Package/base-theme</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

The first time Magento sees a theme, it uses this value to set a `parent_id` in the `theme` table.  This is the source of truth for where a theme's parent is.

However, if you attempt to **change this value after a theme's been added to the system**, Magento fails to update the `parent_id` column, and instantiated `Magento\Theme\Model\Theme` objects will still have the original parent theme.  (Even if you clear the cache.)

I can fix this by manually changing the `parent_id` value -- that seems like a hack.  Where is `parent_id` normally set in Magento's core code, and what user actions trigger this? i.e. is there a way to tell Magento "please re-load this theme"

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this too and the only way I have found to modify this after the theme has been registered is to modify the database directly. Possibly a bug?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED AT 20160310

### Conclusion

**It is always set either via `updateTheme()` or from the collection (via DB) if your `appState->getMode() == AppState::MODE_PRODUCTION`**

### Answer

To answer the question *What is the way to get Magento to reload the theme.xml file* the answer is:

Set the application state to `developer` using `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer` in `.htaccess` (or nginx equivalent) and then log in to the admin area (or refresh any admin route) to trigger `Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin\Registration::beforeDispatch()`.

The theme table in the database is updated due to

```
\\Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin\Registration::updateThemeData()
\\...
$themeData->setParentId($parentTheme->getId());`.
\\...
```

See analysis below for details.

### Analysis

Wow the Magento 2 code seems really complex to me. Have you studied this function `beforeDispatch()` which calls `updateThemeData()` but only `if ($this->appState->getMode() != AppState::MODE_PRODUCTION)`

```
//namespace: namespace Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin;
//class: Registration
//file: app/code/Magento/Theme/Model/Theme/Plugin/Registration.php 

     /**
     * Add new theme from filesystem and update existing
     *
     * @param AbstractAction $subject
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(
        AbstractAction $subject,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        try {
            if ($this->appState->getMode() != AppState::MODE_PRODUCTION) {
                $this->themeRegistration->register();
                $this->updateThemeData();
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
```

Probably you have been through this code.

`beforeDispatch()` is called only via admin routes and not on front-end routes. Here is a trace:

```
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin\Registration->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(122): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 \magento2\var\generation\Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#3 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Dashboard\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#7 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#8 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 \magento2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#12 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 \magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#14 \magento2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

Actually I see `beforeDispatch()` calls `updateThemeData()` which contains this nugget:

```
//namespace: namespace Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin;
//class: Registration
//file: app/code/Magento/Theme/Model/Theme/Plugin/Registration.php 
//function: updateThemeData()

//...
            if ($themeData->getParentTheme()) {
                $parentTheme = $this->themeLoader->getThemeByFullPath(
                    $themeData->getParentTheme()->getFullPath()
                );
                $themeData->setParentId($parentTheme->getId());
            }
//...
```

Which seems to actually (finally) refer to a config XML path `$themeData->getParentTheme()->getFullPath()` but that function still uses `$themeData->getParentTheme()`. Oh I think the logic is '*If I am updating a registered theme that has a parentId in the collection (via the DB) then seek a parent path in the config and update the collection*'. <del>So maybe this is it.</del>

<del>Otherwise I am at a complete loss as to how `Magento\Theme\Model\Theme::getParentTheme()` implements `getParentId()` which is declared in the theme interface. Surely it isn't magic. As you say it needs to come either from the DB via the collection or from the theme's config XML path (if it changed or isn't defined yet) but I can't find a definition of `getParentId()`. Maybe it is always set via `updateTheme()` OR from the collection (via DB) so too bad if your `appState->getMode() == AppState::MODE_PRODUCTION`.</del>

I found it useful to glean information from within `updateThemeData()` by adding some log output:

```
//namespace: namespace Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin;
//class: Registration
//file: app/code/Magento/Theme/Model/Theme/Plugin/Registration.php 
//function: updateThemeData()

//...
            if ($themeData->getParentTheme()) {
                $parentTheme = $this->themeLoader->getThemeByFullPath(
                    $themeData->getParentTheme()->getFullPath()
                );
            $this->logger->addDebug("Theme parent full path ".$themeData->getParentTheme()->getFullPath());
            $this->logger->addDebug("Theme parent new ID ".$parentTheme->getId());                    $themeData->setParentId($parentTheme->getId());
            }
//...
```

Which will log to `/var/log/debug.log`. With application state set to `developer` I can see the parent ID is always set on every admin page refresh whether it was changed in `theme.xml` or not. With application state `production` the function is never run so I conclude:

**It is always set via `updateTheme()` OR from the collection (via DB) so too bad if your `appState->getMode() == AppState::MODE_PRODUCTION`**

I think you probably are all in `developer` app state. `default` app state will trigger `updateThemeData()` too of course. In further debugging I logged the theme full path for the parent theme of Luma which was `frontend/Magento/blank`. The capital `M` surprised me so maybe something to watch out for.

Answer (score 2):

The above didn't seem to work for me, so I went with the hack.

Hope it helps someone.

```
using the command line

 mysql

 SHOW databases;

 use magento; (or whatever your DB's name is)

 SHOW tables

 SELECT * FROM theme; 

(Check the **parent_id** of theme in question, it should be the same number as **theme_id** of theme you want as the parent)
```

if it is not, change it.

```
 UPDATE theme SET parent_id  = '[value]' WHERE theme_title = '[Theme name]';

then quit mysql;

 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

or

```
grunt clean:[theme] (For example:  grunt clean:blank)

grunt exec:[theme]

grunt less:[theme]
```