# How to enable custom admin theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, theme

I have followed the instructions here: [How to create admin theme for Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59206/how-to-create-admin-theme-for-magento2)

and here: [How to change backend admin theme in Magento 2.0.7 +](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118095/how-to-change-backend-admin-theme-in-magento-2-0-7)

and I still dont understand what I'm supposed to do to get my theme to show up in the backend. I have created my theme in `app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/themename` and its got a `theme.xml` and a `registration.php` (same as my frontend theme, which is working nicely). However, the above instructions talk about about a `etc/di.xml` which I have no idea where to place (or is that even the solution?)

Googling has got me absolutely nowhere, Magento 2 official docs suck (as always) so no help there.

So, summa summarum: how to enable my custom admin theme?

Answer (score 15):

Thank you @Alex! Your solution worked for me! I can see from the source that admin area is using my theme now.

Steps:

1. create a new **theme** in `app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Themename`. In that directory, create a `theme.xml`:

`<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Theme Tile</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> 
</theme>`

And a registration.php:

`<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Vendor/Themename',
    __DIR__
);`

2. Either create new module for deploying your theme, or use some existing module; either way, in your **modules** `module.xml` add the `sequence` xml element to make sure your theme gets loaded last.

`<config>
    <module name="My_Custommodule" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>`

and in your custom **modules** `etc/di.xml` add the fragment that specifies the admin theme to use:
`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/Themename</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>`

3. run `setup:upgrade` and voila! Check what theme is being used by viewing source: all css and js files should now be loaded from `/pub/static/adminhtml/Vendor/Themename/[language]/....`

**However, all admin pages seems to be missing styles**. I am in developer mode, and did a `setup:static-content:deploy [languages]` (with no errors) but that did not resolve the issue. I have had this same issue on the frontend as well, but cant remember how I fixed it.. do I need to copy js and css files from `magento-backend` module to make this work?

**ISSUE RESOLVED**: it appears I have run into this issue: [Correct way to Update a Theme's Parent in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102653/correct-way-to-update-a-themes-parent-in-magento-2) where if I install my theme and then change the parent to something else in `theme.xml`, it will no be updated in the database and it wont take effect. I had initially put Magento/blank in the parent-element, and that obviously did not work at all, and changing it to Magento/backend later did not help either (as per the link above). So I went in the database and set the parent_id for my theme by hand. And just like that, everything works :)

Comment: I can see (comparing to another installation with the default admin theme) that `/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/[language]/css/styles.css`  is not referenced in the source. Looking at `vendor/magento/magento-backend/view` and the layout files, it's not referenced there either. Apparently, it's specified in `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml` but how do I get it to show up in my theme as well?

Comment: Does you theme inherit from from Magento Backend or no?

Comment: @Alex yes it does, as you can see in my `theme.xml` above, and now I have it ALMOST working: I created a `app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and in that file I specified 

`<css src="css/styles.css" />`

Then I copied the css-file over to my theme from `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles.css` and now I can see it in the source and things are looking better. However, something crucial still appears to be missing, backend now has styles but layout is all screwed.

Comment: Can we have sample Admin theme Link on GitHub?

Answer (score 4):

To apply the Admin theme, you need to create a new module and specify it there:

1. Make sure you are in developer mode.
2. Create a separate `MyVendor_MyBackendTheme` module. (similar to https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-minimal for example, but do not forget to edit the `module.xml` and `registration.php` if you decide to use it). In `module.xml` specify that the `Magento_Theme` module loads before you module by adding:

```
    <module name="MyVendor_MyBackendTheme" setup_version="2.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
```

3. Add the `<module>/etc/di.xml`, where add the following node:

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
    <arguments>
         <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">your_vendor_dir/your_theme_dir</item>
         </argument>
     </arguments> 
</type>
```

4. Run the `magento setup:upgrade` command.
5. Open the Admin and view the new theme applied (hopefully:)).

Comment: p.s.: we plan to add the official doc soon

Comment: So you mean I have to create a complete module (in addition to my theme) just to deploy my admin theme? What is this madness!?

Comment: i have another module I have created for this webstore, I assume I can use that to specify the admin theme. Will let you know how that pans out :)

Comment: Yes, of course you can use the existing custom module.

Comment: Can we have link to download sample admin theme?

Comment: HI @Alex Thanks for explanation. Can we have sample Admin Theme on github?