# Magento 2: How to override Adminhtml "Shipping & Handling Information" Information

Tags: magento2, module, orders, adminhtml, sales-order

I'm following https://ranasohel.me/2015/10/02/how-to-overwrite-sales-view-order-phtml-file-in-magento2/

I would like to override `magento\vendor\magento\module-shipping\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml`

How to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I've faced the same issue if i refrence to **order_info** block, you need to reference to **order_shipping_view** block instead

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_shipping_view">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml**

```
<h1> Override Success </h1>
<h2> Put Your desire content here </h2>
```

flush magento cache, do setup:upgrade

Answer (score 4):

One of the easiest way is that we will create a new backend admin: [How to enable custom admin theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124336/how-to-enable-custom-admin-theme-in-magento-2).

```
app/design/adminhtml/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Shipping/templates/order/view/info.phtml
```

The second way, set our custom template

*app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml*

```
<referenceBlock name='order_info'>
  <arguments>
    <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Load custom module layout after shipping

*app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/module.xml*

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Does is need to create new theme for this? Can't we override with Magento Default Backend Theme?

Comment: It depends on your need. If you don't need to create a custom theme, we can choose the second.

Comment: Ok I'm using Second Way. `sales_order_view.xml` is `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>` Where to put `sequence` code?

Comment: In `etc/module.xml`

Comment: So my `module.xml` will be `<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Shipping"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>`

Comment: Yes, the `module.xml` should be

Comment: Seems not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49340/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: HI @Khoa http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148516/magento-2-how-to-enable-newly-created-admin-theme-override-module

Comment: I tried to do this but ultimately learned another vendor module (temando-shipping) was already doing it. So how can I over-ride the over-ride?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue with version 2.3.2.  I could not get the above solutions to work for some reason.  Finally I just tried copying the full xml from  `vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` to my own extension `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

You then just need to copy the template file `Magento_Shipping::order/view/info.phtml` and move it to you custom extension and make the changes you need.