# Magento 2: How to enable newly created admin theme & override module?

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, overrides, custom

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2.

I have followed Magento StackExchange Questions/Answer for this.

Still having issues.

I would like to Override [Magento 2: How to override Adminhtml "Shipping & Handling Information" Information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148102/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-shipping-handling-information-informati) Using Magento Admin Theme.

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\Themename\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Vendor/Themename',
    __DIR__
);
```

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\Themename\theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Theme Tile</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> 
</theme>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Backend\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Custom_Backend', __DIR__
);
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Backend\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Backend" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Backend\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Magento/backend</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Shipping\templates\order\view\info.phtml**

```
echo "hi";
exit;
```

I have run below commands as well

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

What i'm still missing?

New theme entry shows in `theme` table

I'm in developer mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow the Magento guide:

- Create an Admin theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html
- Apply an Admin theme: **we need to create a new module**: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

There is a note that your `magento\app\code\Custom\Backend\etc\di.xml` should be:

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design"> 
<arguments> 
  <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array"> 
     <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/Themename</item> 
  </argument> 
</arguments> 
</type>
```

Comment: What i'm missing in above ones?

Comment: Don't need `magento\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Shipping\etc\module.xml`,  `magento\app\design\adminhtml\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Shipping\etc\di.xml`. **We need to create a new module to apply the custom theme**

Comment: How & where to check your New Admin Theme is applied? I would like to override that Shipping Block so i need to remove that?

Comment: `magnto/app/code/Custom/Backend/etc/module.xml` In `<sequence><module name="Vendor_Themename"/></sequence>` or `<sequence><module name="Magento_Backend"/></sequence>`

Comment: Use `<sequence><module name="Magento_Theme"/></sequence>`.

Comment: If we want to check your New Admin Theme is applied, you should check **Source** in your Browser.

Comment: Shipping related files where i need to put in `app\design` right?

Comment: Yes, `app/design/adminhtml`

Comment: HI @Khoa Please check my updated question. Still it's not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49465/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ankit-shah).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Khoa for u r excellent help. Finally get solved :)