# How to override .phtml files in Magento 2 for backend

Tags: magento2, overrides, backend, phtml

I want to customize image file upload tab, So it required to override some `.phtml` files in following locations.

So I want to know, how to override `.phtml` files in

**/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml**

Answer (score 1):

1st create ur Admin Theme by using below guide

[Magento 2: How to enable newly created admin theme & override module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148516/magento-2-how-to-enable-newly-created-admin-theme-override-module)

or

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Ur file will be here

**magento\app\design\adminhtml\YourVendor\YourThemeName\Magento_Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\media\uploader.phtml**

Comment: Can i change phtml files like in magento 1.x, without create custom module

Comment: Standard way is create your Custom Theme & override Core file which u want. Purpose when Magento version upgrades, ur changes remains

Comment: File Path should be
magento\app\design\adminhtml\YourVendor\YourThemeName\Magento_Backend\templates\media\uploader.phtml