# How to override adminhtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides

We have to override vendor adminhtml file in magento2.

\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\info.phtml

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to override the corresponding layout xml to accomplish this

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148102/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-shipping-handling-information-informati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom module for that :

Try following way:

Create **sales_order_view.xml** at

> app/code/Your_VendorName/Your_ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Add below code in **sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then Copy info.phtml file from

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

To

> app/code/Your_Vendor/Your_Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Comment: @AlinLupoiu Happy to help !! Keep helping :)

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

You can create your **module** and place this file in

```
app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml
```

And then add this code

```
<referenceBlock name='order_info'>
  <arguments>
    <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Namespace_Modulename::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

and then create the template phtml file and place your code there.

```
app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml
```

**Method 2**

Another easy method is by placing the file in

```
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Shipping/templates/order/view/info.phtml
```