# Changing phtml file via /app

Tags: magento2.3, phtml

In a previous question i asked where to find items.phtml file.

I found it and did the configuration and it worked. But when i did this it was via this path: vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtml.

I read somewhere that they do not recommend to any changes via /vendor but do this via /app/design/adminhtml/custom_vendor/custom_theme/ and so on.

What i did was i downloaded the items.phtml (un-fonfigured) and i did the change and tried to add this file to my created path:
/app/design/adminhtml/custom_vendor/custom_theme/templates/create/items.phtml

after doing the setup:upgrade and setup:deploy, cleared cache and re-indexed nothing happen.

Can anyone help and tell me what i have done wrong?

Any tips and help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Magento 2: How to override Adminhtml "Shipping & Handling Information" Information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148102/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-shipping-handling-information-informati) 
and [How to enable custom admin theme in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124336/how-to-enable-custom-admin-theme-in-magento-2)
it will walk you through how to override adminhtml template file through overriding the template in `app/design` and in new theme and how to activate it.

Also this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205450/52729 will guide you on overriding adminhtml template file by creating new module

Comment: Thank you for you answer and the links. will have a look and see if i can do this. 

I have another question, is all of this needed if i just gonna add "checked" after the check box code in items.phtml file? What is the risk if i do this straight in the file?

Comment: If i understand the guides correctly they are doing changes on the website itself?
What I'm trying to achieve is to change an admin "checkbox" so it is checked as default. Will it be safe to change it directly in the items.phtml or should i do it another way?